Handling exported Flag in BroadcastReceiver in Xamarin.Android
I'm developing an Android app using Xamarin.Android where I was subscribing to ConnectivityChanged like this:
//The subscription
Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;

//The code to execute on connectivity change
private async void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsConnected = e.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet;

    await GoNoInternetPage();
}


Now that I have upgrade the android sdk version to api 34 I was getting this error:
Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'com.advansys.ibanking.coopdepop: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts'
So I had to register manually the BroadcastReceiver so I did that and the app was working just like new again, the problem comes when I test the app on emulator api 25 and lower that the app freezes when I change the conectivity, my app currenly has minSdkVersion set to api 22 and I do not want to increase the version because I got some clients using those versions, if anyone can help I'll appreciate it
This is what i did to fix the situation for api 34
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" })]
public class BCWifiSignal : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

    public Action OnWifiSignalChanged { get; set; }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        OnWifiSignalChanged();
    }
}

This is how I'm registerirng/unregistering the broadcast:
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    private BCWifiSignal _bCWifiSignal;
    private BCWifiSignal2 _bCWifiSignal2;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetLocale();
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
    UserDialogs.Init(this);
    CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    RegisterOnWifiSignalChanged();
    
    LoadApplication(new App());
}

private void RegisterOnWifiSignalChanged()
{
    _bCWifiSignal = new BCWifiSignal();
    _bCWifiSignal.OnWifiSignalChanged += OnWifiSignalChangedReciever;
    RegisterReceiver(_bCWifiSignal, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
}

private void OnWifiSignalChangedReciever() { }

protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    
    _bCWifiSignal.OnWifiSignalChanged -= OnWifiSignalChangedReciever;
    UnregisterReceiver(_bCWifiSignal);
}
}


Did you solve it? I am getting the same error in my xamarin android project, I couldn't fix it.
